# Flutter error with flutter webview plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When I put this code in my widget, I get this error

```
Widget _buildWebView(){
  return const Webview(
    initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

  );
}
```

The named parameter `initialUrl` isn't defined.

Comment: can you show your error in console

Comment: I don't have any error with your code. Can you add more informations?

Comment: I resolved the problem. Just flutter clean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Widget _buildWebView(){
  return const WebView(
    initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

  );
}
```

try this way